# Como fazer a remoção de caracteres especiais de string em C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

`Regex.Replace()` é uma ótima solução para remover acentuação.

Agora só não consigo é fazer a remoção de um tipo de carácter, tenho uma string que receber o texto **"1° Lugar Geral"**, na string tem o caractere **°**, há uma lista para estes tipos de caracteres? Como vocês estão fazendo para eliminá-lo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não conheço uma lista específica para esses tipos de caracteres.

Uma abordagem que você pode utilizar é o inverso: subistituir todos os caracteres que **não** pertencem a um certo intervalo, com um intervalo negado `[^ ]`

**Exemplo**

`(?i)` - Torna a *regex case incensitive*

`[^0-9a-záéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõç\s]` - Casa todos caracteres que não são dos intervalos de A a Z (`a-z`), 0 a 9 (`0-9`), espaços e afins (`\s`) e acentuados (`áéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõç`)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "Você chegou em 1º lugar, Parabéns!";
      string pattern = @"(?i)[^0-9a-záéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõç\s]";
      string replacement = "";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

      Console.WriteLine("String Original: {0}", input);
      Console.WriteLine("String tratada : {0}", result);                             
   }
}
```

**Edição**

O bacana das expressões regulares é que podemos resolver o mesmo problema de diversas formas. Fazendo alguns testes aqui me lembrei do "ou" `|` e assim consegui aplicar `[^/w/s]` (Lista negada de alfanuméricos com acentos e espaços) seguido de `[ºª]`, resultando assim no resultado esperado de forma mais limpa: `[^\w\s]|[ºª]`

Comment: Sua rotina está mais explicada, gostei e funciona bem! Obrigado!

Comment: @gmsantos o acento circunflexo na palavra **você** e o acento em **Parabéns** ainda persiste, como retirar esses acentos ?

Comment: @AdrianoSUV acredito que isso seja outra pergunta

Answer (score 19):

Eu usaria uma expressão regular simples que traga apenas letras e números:

```
Regex.Replace(minhaString, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

Comment: Opa, apenas para apontar a classe `\W` (qualquer carácter que não seja uma palavra). **Fonte**: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#character_classes)

Comment: A resposta do @Cigano é também o que eu faria: apenas não esqueça de incluir também um " " para que os espaços também sejam aceitos.

Comment: `\W` irá casar º . `^0-9a-zA-Z` não casa caracteres acentuados. Única regex que vejo para esse seria uma lista negada incluindo caracteres acentuados.

Comment: Funciona muito bem, obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 4):

Resolvi responder porque a resposta mais votada não faz o que é pedido e outra menos votada é muito complexa e ineficiente, nem sei se fazer certo. A resposta aceita parece estar mais correta, embora tenha alguns problemas, provavelmente por descuido mais do q entendimento errado da pergunta, mas nem todo mundo gosta de usar Regex, então dou uma solução simples, moderna e eficiente sem RegEx:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;
                    
var texto = "Você chegou em 1º lugar, Parabéns!";
StringBuilder novo = new(texto.Length);
foreach (var c in texto) if ("1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZáéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõçÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕÇ ".IndexOf(c) >= 0) novo.Append(c);
WriteLine(novo);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tRUN4Z). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NiNNnK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/TrimSpecials.cs).

É de se questionar se deveria mesmo tirar os caracteres especiais e não substituir por outros, porque o texto fica esquisito sem ter nada ali, talvez alguns caracteres deveriam ser apenas trocados por outros mais simples mas que dê o mesmo sentido. E não me preocupei em manter caracteres como a exclamação, a pergunta não deixa claro que ele deve ser removido ou não, mas isso é fácil de resolver se for necessário.

Eu não fiz um *benchmark*, mas tenho quase certeza que este código é mais rápido que RegEx, é difícil RegEx ser mais rápido, e se ele for é porque este meu pode ser mais bem feito.

Answer (score 3):

Segue um simples método que fiz onde mantém apenas números e letras sem acentos, e retira todos os carácteres especiais possíveis.

```
 public static string ObterStringSemAcentosECaracteresEspeciais(string str)
        {
            /** Troca os caracteres acentuados por não acentuados **/
            string[] acentos = new string[] { "ç", "Ç", "á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú", "ý", "Á", "É", "Í", "Ó", "Ú", "Ý", "à", "è", "ì", "ò", "ù", "À", "È", "Ì", "Ò", "Ù", "ã", "õ", "ñ", "ä", "ë", "ï", "ö", "ü", "ÿ", "Ä", "Ë", "Ï", "Ö", "Ü", "Ã", "Õ", "Ñ", "â", "ê", "î", "ô", "û", "Â", "Ê", "Î", "Ô", "Û" };
            string[] semAcento = new string[] { "c", "C", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "a", "o", "n", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "A", "O", "N", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U" };

            for (int i = 0; i < acentos.Length; i++)
            {
                str = str.Replace(acentos[i], semAcento[i]);
            }
            /** Troca os caracteres especiais da string por "" **/
            string[] caracteresEspeciais = { "¹", "²", "³", "£", "¢", "¬", "º", "¨", "\"", "'", ".", ",", "-", ":", "(", ")", "ª", "|", "\\\\", "°", "_", "@", "#", "!", "$", "%", "&", "*", ";", "/", "<", ">", "?","[", "]", "{", "}", "=", "+", "§" ,"´", "`", "^", "~" };

            for (int i = 0; i < caracteresEspeciais.Length; i++)
            {
                str = str.Replace(caracteresEspeciais[i], "");
            }

            /** Troca os caracteres especiais da string por " " **/
            str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\w\.@-]", " ",
                                RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));

            return str.Trim();
        }
```