# Remover acentos e símbolos com regex

Tags: c#, regex

Preciso remover os **acentos** e substituir o simbolo **&** dessa string: **"Indústria e Comércio de produtos manufaturados & Agregados, poços, fabricados e 1º ..."**, porém não funciona corretamente do jeito que fiz:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string _textoNAOFormatado = @"Indústria e Comércio de produtos manufaturados & Agregados, poços, fabricados e 1º ...";
            string _pattern = @"(?i)[^0-9a-záéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõç\s]";
            Regex _rgx = new Regex(_pattern);
            string _textoFormatado = _rgx.Replace(_textoNAOFormatado, "");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", _textoFormatado);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
}
```

Basei-me nesse post [Regex - Remoção de Caracteres Especiais C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25924/regex-remo%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-caracteres-especiais-c), mas não funciona, os acentos persistem e não consigui tirar o **&**, o retorno é esse:

"Indústria e Comércio de produtos manufaturados  Agregados poços fabricados e 1 ", preciso que fica assim:
"IND**U**STRIA E COM**E**RCIO DE PRODUTOS MANUFATURADOS **E** AGREGADOS PO**C**OS FABRICADOS E 1"

Comment: Não é duplicada, pois a diferença entre os post é que essa pergunta é  como fazer com regex.

Comment: Não deveria ser fechado. Claramente uma pergunta diferente